# Sails.js and Mocha: Using supertest: route issue when controller in coustom folder like api\controllers is moved to api\controllers\admin

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js, supertest

While I am doing testing code if I put controller in default position 'api\controllers\'. It's running perfectly without error but when I am changing it to 'api\controllers\admin\'. It gives error.

==> when controller at default position 'api\controllers\'

my code is 
in config/routes.js

```
'post /state/create': 'StateController.create',
```

and testing code is

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('StateController', function() {

describe('#create()', function() {

    it('State already in table /create', function (done) {
        request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post('/state/create/')  //Path and method
            .send({ name: 'gujarat', country_id: '55d452f20424cda40df0f3de' })
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(800)
            .end(function(err, res){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(res.body);
                if(res){
                    if(res.body.message == 'State already in table'){
                        done();
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
});
```

I got the successful result like

```
  StateController
#create()
{ flag: false,
  data: 'gujarat',
  message: 'State already in table',
  code: 800 }
  √ State already in table /create (171ms)
```

==> But when I changed controller's position to 'api\controllers\admin\'

route.js

```
'post /admin/state/create': 'admin/StateController.create',
```

and in testing code

```
.post('/state/create/')
```

to

```
.post('/admin/state/create/')
```

I got error

```
1) StateController #create() State already in table /create:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined
  at Test._assertHeader (D:\Sails Projects\InterJewel\IJ\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:208:19)
  at Test._assertFunction (D:\Sails Projects\InterJewel\IJ\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:247:11)
  at Test.assert (D:\Sails Projects\InterJewel\IJ\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:148:18)
  at Server.assert (D:\Sails Projects\InterJewel\IJ\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:127:12)
  at net.js:1392:10
```

reference link - http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing